# Why can't I get the gotour with go get?

Tags: mercurial, go

So I decided I wanted to learn [go](http://golang.org/), and so I started the [tour](http://tour.golang.org/). In [stage 3](http://tour.golang.org/#3) of that tour they recommend to use go to checkout a copy of the tour and run it locally, so I installed go for mac via the recommended [installer package](http://code.google.com/p/go/downloads/list?q=OpSys-Darwin).

I then had the `go` command available, so I ran `go get code.google.com/p/go-tour/gotour` as it suggests in the tour.

It says "and then run the resultant gotour executable" in the tour. No executable was to be found.

The output from `go get` was this:

```
package code.google.com/p/go-tour/gotour: Get https://code.google.com/p/go-tour/source/checkout?repo=: EOF
```

I know EOF means end of file but I'm not sure as to whether that was an error message or not.

I have `hg` installed:

```
$ hg --version
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 2.3.1)
```

And I set my `$GOPATH` (and the file doesn't appear there):

```
echo $GOPATH
/Users/alex/.golib
```

Running `go env` returns this:

```
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOBIN=""
GOARCH="386"
GOCHAR="8"
GOOS="darwin"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="386"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_386"
GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m32 -pthread -fno-common"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

If it helps, I'm using [fish](http://ridiculousfish.com/shell/) as my shell.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

a `go get` (contrary to `go get -u`) will get, compile *and install* the go module you want in `$GOPATH`.
The executable `gotour` will be in `$GOPATH/bin`.

So make sure you have your `$GOPATH/bin` in your path.

When executed, you should see:

```
2012/09/15 10:43:57 Serving content from $GOPATH/src/code.google.com/p/go-tour
2012/09/15 10:43:57 Open your web browser and visit http://127.0.0.1:3999/
```

Note (personal preference): I would use a more visible path than `/Users/alex/.golib`: `/Users/alex/go`
`GOPATH` isn't just to get some libs, but to develop all your go projects.

Comment: I created the directory `/Users/alex/Documents/Development/go` and set `GOPATH` to that, created the `bin` directory inside of that, and added it to my path, but when I run `go get` my `bin` directory is stil empty :( - do you know if the output I'm getting is normal?

Comment: @AlexCoplan no I don't know, unless there is some kind of side effect with `fish`. But try and go to `/Users/alex/Documents/Development/go/src/code.google.com/p/go-tour`, and type in there: `go install`. See if that doesn't compile and properly install `gotour` in your `$GOPATH/bin`.